# Supervisord | Unsupported syscall

Tags: php, symfony, google-cloud-platform, supervisord, google-cloud-run

I try to use supervisord in order to link PHP & Nginx, my container runs locally but once pushed to Cloud Run, I go a 502 error which informs me that the PHP socket can't be found.

I have a non-Alpine image which runs with the same configuration and everything goes right, I've tried to use the PHP default port (9000) and everything works but I've seen that using Unix socket can be a better idea.

Here's the Dockerfile used:

```
FROM php:7.3.5-alpine3.9 as base

ARG REVISION

LABEL org.opencontainers.image.authors=contact@guillaumeloulier.fr
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.source=https://gitlab.com/Guikingone/Portfolio
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.revision=$REVISION

ENV APP_DIR=/srv/app \
    APP_ENV=prod \
    APP_FRONT_CONTROLLER=index.php \
    APP_LOCALE=fr \
    APP_USER=portfolio-user \
    APP_USER_GROUP=portfolio \
    APP_PORT=8080 \
    COMPOSER_DIR=/opt/composer \
    COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1 \
    NGINX_DIR=/etc/nginx \
    NGINX_VERSION=1.14.2-r1 \
    PHP_FPM_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/ \
    SUPERVISORD_CONF_DIR=/etc/supervisor \
    SUPERVISOR_VERSION=3.3.4-r1 \
    BUILD_SCRIPTS_DIR=/build-scripts

# Supervisord conf to be copied at the end.
COPY docker/prod/php/scripts/*.sh $BUILD_SCRIPTS_DIR/

# Core dependencies installation (installed as a virtual package in order to remove it later)
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps $PHPIZE_DEPS \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .bash bash=4.4.19-r1 \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .core-php-deps icu-dev=62.1-r0 \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
        intl \
        opcache \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-enable opcache \
    && apk del .build-deps .phpize-deps-configure

# User creation
RUN apk add --no-cache --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/ --allow-untrusted --virtual .user-deps gosu=1.10-r0 \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    && addgroup $APP_USER_GROUP \
    && adduser -D -h /home/portfolio -s /bin/bash -G $APP_USER_GROUP $APP_USER \
    && chown -R $APP_USER $BUILD_SCRIPTS_DIR \
    && apk del .user-deps

# Nginx & Supervisor installation
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .http-deps nginx=$NGINX_VERSION supervisor=$SUPERVISOR_VERSION \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    && ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

RUN mkdir -p $APP_DIR $BUILD_SCRIPTS_DIR \
    && chown -R $APP_USER $APP_DIR \
    && chmod -R 755 $APP_DIR

COPY docker/prod/php/conf/php.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini
COPY docker/prod/php/conf/fpm.conf $PHP_FPM_CONF_DIR/fpm.conf
COPY docker/prod/nginx/conf/nginx.conf $NGINX_DIR/nginx.conf
COPY docker/prod/supervisord/supervisord.conf $SUPERVISORD_CONF_DIR/supervisord.conf

# Used to check that PHP-FPM works
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --timeout=3s \
  CMD curl -f http://localhost/ping || exit 1

EXPOSE $APP_PORT 443

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-n", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]

# Production build
FROM base as production

COPY docker/prod/nginx/conf/portfolio.conf $NGINX_DIR/conf.d/portfolio.conf

WORKDIR $APP_DIR

COPY . .

# The vendors are installed after the whole project is copied, this way, we can dump the autoload properly.
# The unrequired directories are also removed.
RUN /bin/bash "$BUILD_SCRIPTS_DIR/install_composer.sh" \
    && /bin/bash "$BUILD_SCRIPTS_DIR/composer_dependencies.sh" \
    && rm -rf $BUILD_SCRIPTS_DIR \
        /usr/bin/git* \
        /lib/apk/db/installed \
        /usr/local/bin/composer \
        node_modules/
```

And here's the supervisor configuration file:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon = true
logfile = /dev/null
logfile_maxbytes = 0
pidfile = /var/run/supervisord.pid
loglevel = INFO

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[program:php-fpm]
command = /usr/local/sbin/php-fpm
autostart = true
autorestart = true
priority = 5
stdout_logfile = /dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 0
stderr_logfile = /dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 0

[program:nginx]
command = /usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
autostart = true
autorestart = true
priority = 10
stdout_events_enabled = true
stderr_events_enabled = true
stdout_logfile = /dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 0
stderr_logfile = /dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 0

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/**/*.conf
```

Here's the error log in StackDriver logging linked to the container sandox:

```
2019-05-19 11:31:50.246 CEST
Container Sandbox Limitation: Unsupported syscall prctl(0x4,0x1,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x20)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're trying to run nginx and php-fpm under supervisord? That makes no sense at all. nginx and php-fpm already *do* what supervisord does.

Comment: Your unsupported syscall is PR_SET_DUMPABLE. Since you cannot control process core dumps, this call failing does not matter to you (affect your software). This also means that this message is not related to your 502 error. In your case, the 502 error is probably related to your PHP program crashing. I would enable PHP debugging.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, even if the container runs locally?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking with "container runs locally"? Not enough details to understand your comment.

Comment: Do you confirm the container runs locally with [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local)? but fails when deployed to Cloud Run? If so, this might be a limitation with Cloud Run's container sandbox. 
I opened an internal bug to investigate, feel free to open a public issue in [the Cloud Run issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#search_for_or_create_bugs_and_feature_requests_by_product) too.

Comment: Hi @Steren, yes, the container runs locally following the dedicated instructions, I'm gonna open a public issue to complete yours :) 

@JohnHanley "container runs locally" -> run on my machine using the `docker run --publish 8080:8080 imagetag` command.